# PHPUnit + Selenium : error

Tags: configuration, selenium, phpunit

I recently tried to install PHPUnit and Selenium, but I'm running into some errors:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException::getCustomMessage() in /phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php on line 1041
```

Did I forget something in my install ? I'm using the last version available on Git.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your version of PHPUnit_Selenium.
PHPUnit doesn't include Selenium extension since version 3.6 and you have to install/upgrade it manually.

```
pear upgrade phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
```

or

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to reinstall - use [PEAR](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://pear.php.net/&rct=j&q=php%20pear&ei=XZyYTovpGqWOsQKe44jABA&usg=AFQjCNFNYtqBINWU49rA1foldfVeXhWm-Q&sig2=lyClqAMNmxN-oetqK-t-_Q&cad=rja)